# How to customize the history display for the requester

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

I need to configure the display history for the requester, in particular, the date of the last change should be displayed not in the form of how many days have passed since the last change, but simply the date of the last change. How can I settle this?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StJ4U.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be version service or version service object which will be fetching all those details in script. You can modify that template to show that details.